# class selector link using a href

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm asking what may be a silly question, and I apologize in advance.

I am working on something without access to the back end. I have this annoying little "magic box" where I can use HTML / CSS.
My question is this: I have a class with a link and I'm trying to hide that specific one.
So in this case I'm trying to hide this .ad_link href="/colt?ban-link=141"
I don't want to hide the entire .ad_link class, Just the specific class with that href attached to it.  There are more items under the ad_link class that need to stay unhidden.

I hope my question makes enough sense, please let me know if I need to clarify more.

bigesgunshop.com It's located under the left side, the "colt" image/link

Comment: Can you post the relevant html so we can see what you have to work with?  There may be an alternative solution that might work but we can't know without seeing the markup.

Comment: I should mention that I can only use HTML and CSS, and can only modify pieces of the page using div ID's or class.

So what I have so far is this:

<style type="html/css">
 .ad_link [href='/colt?ban-link=141'] { 
display: none !important;
}
</style>

Comment: http://bigesgunshop.com/
It's located under the left side, the "colt" image/link

Comment: can't access it, I'm outside of US and getting: "This website is for U.S. customers only."

Comment: Should work if you use a proxy. Here try this, might need to refresh once or twice until it loads correctly though.
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-4/encoded/Oi8vYmlnZXNndW5zaG9wLmNvbS8%3D&f=norefer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.ad_link[href="/colt?ban-link=141"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

or if you can add another class to this link, just add `hidden` defined as:

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree to @pawel, but this approach is not very maintainable.

I suggest it's in this case better to hide with inline style:

```
<a href="/colt?ban-link=141" style="display: none;">Foo</a>
```

Or use an class with more importance to hide the link.

Comment: I like the idea of adding another class, @Squeezit if you can edit classes just add something like "hidden-link" and define it as .hidden-link { display: none !important; }

Comment: I can't exactly edit them, I can only modify them from this "magic box"
Not too sure how to explain it, and not sure what they're called.  Think of Myspace if you're familiar with that old thing. I don't know how it works now, but years back you used to be able to add code for your page without actually accessing the back end. That's what I'm currently doing for this site, I can modify things on the side.  I am a bit of a beginner to CSS.

Comment: try adding !important to my previous answer then

Comment: I think I deleted your comment by mistake, sorry this site is a bit weird for me the way I can't just respond.

I did try though, here's what I have currently.
<style type="text/css"> .ad_link[href="/colt?ban-link=141"] {
  display: none !important;
}</style>

Comment: when I opened it in Chrome's Web Inspector it somehow looks like this: "<style type="text/css"> .ad_link[href="/colt?ban-link=141"] {<br />
  display: none !important;<br />
}</style>" Notice the strange <br/> tags. Try removing any whitespace.

Comment: Ha, that was it.  I deleted an extra space in each part and it is now working. Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool, did you intended to accept this answer though? :P

Comment: I intended to accept your answer, did I do it wrong? :/

Comment: You've accepted Henri's answer, which is cool though :) just asking :)

Comment: I messed up your answer, so I copied and pasted what you wrote and accepted your answer :P